# Using the script i have, I am able to show .menu on click, but can not get it to disappear again on second click to return to default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav').hide();
        $(".menu").click( function() {
            $(".menu").toggleClass("close");
            $('.nav').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: you always `$('.nav').show();` on every click - is this what you wanted?

Comment: Use `$('.nav').toggle();` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav').hide(); //Class nav in the begin should be closed.
    $(".menu").click( function() {
        $(".menu").toggleClass("close");
        $('.nav').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Hope 'll help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `toggle` will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav').hide();
    $(".menu").click( function() {
        $(".menu").toggleClass("close");
        $('.nav').toggle();
    });
});
```